# How can I fix the following method?

Tags: c#, loops, ftp

I made a method which can scan an ftp server. It has two parts in an if...else statement. The first part in the if runs when the list of directories equals to 0, and separate the folders from the files( and put them into that list). Then(because the list is no more empty) the else statement should runs. It has a foreach loop which check all elements of the list and concat them to the ftp address and scan that folder. And here's the problem. Looks like it turn into an infinite loop. I only want to check the folders on the server and break the loop but looks like I cannot find a useful solution.

Here's the code:

```
internal void ListFilesOnServer()
        {
            ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
            if (directories.Count == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    FtpWebRequest ftpwrq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server);
                    ftpwrq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, passw);
                    ftpwrq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                    ftpwrq.KeepAlive = false;
                    FtpWebResponse fresponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpwrq.GetResponse();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fresponse.GetResponseStream());
                    string temp = "";
                    while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        files.Add(temp);
                    }
                    temp = String.Empty;
                    sr.Close();
                    fresponse.Close();
                    DirOrFile(files);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string file in directories.ToArray())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FtpWebRequest ftpwrq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server+"/"+file);
                        ftpwrq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, passw);
                        ftpwrq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                        ftpwrq.KeepAlive = false;
                        FtpWebResponse fresponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpwrq.GetResponse();
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fresponse.GetResponseStream());
                        string temp = "";
                        while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            files.Add(temp);
                        }
                        temp = String.Empty;
                        sr.Close();
                        fresponse.Close();
                        DirOrFile(files);
                    }
                    catch(ArgumentException)
                    {

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            ListFilesOnServer();
        }
```

Comment: Where does it get stuck? did you check it using breakpoints?

Comment: The else statement wont run after the if, just have code follow.an if statement if you want this to happen (no else)

Comment: You get stuck in a loop because you call the function recursively without ever setting directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop is because you don't have a way to break out of the recursion.

The pattern for recursion looks like this

```
MyRecursiveMethod()
{
    if (conditions)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        MyRecursiveMethod()
    }
}
```

Here's how I might go about rewriting this code to make it work for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class FtpTest
    {
        string server = "servier/";
        string user = "user";
        SecureString passw = new SecureString();

        public List<string> GetFilesOnServer()
        {
            return GetFilesOnServer(server);
        }

        public List<string> GetFilesOnServer(string dir)
        {
            var root = GetDirectoryContents(dir);
            var files = new List<string>();

            foreach (string name in root)
            {
                var path = GetFullPath(dir, name);
                if (IsDirectory(name))
                {
                    var subFiles = GetFilesOnServer(path);
                    files.AddRange(subFiles);
                }
                else
                {
                    files.Add(path);
                }
            }

            return files;
        }

        public List<string> GetDirectoryContents(string dir)
        {
            var files = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                var ftpwrq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(dir);
                ftpwrq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, passw);
                ftpwrq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                ftpwrq.KeepAlive = false;
                var fresponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpwrq.GetResponse();
                var sr = new StreamReader(fresponse.GetResponseStream());
                string fileName = "";
                while ((fileName = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    files.Add(fileName);
                }
                sr.Close();
                fresponse.Close();
                return files;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

            return files;
        }

        public static string GetFullPath(string dir, string file)
        {
            string path = dir;
            if (!path.EndsWith("/"))
                path += "/";
            path += file;
            return path;
        }

        public static bool IsDirectory(string name)
        {
            return name.IndexOf(".") > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I only recursively call into GetFilesOnServer if the item retrieved is a directory. I've also refactored out the code that grabs the contents on the FTP server into a non-recursive method.

Hope this helps you out.